# CSRF Error When going from Perl to Django

Tags: django, perl, django-csrf

I have a site where users can log in from a perl front end and then are redirected to a django site.  The site is on the same domain, maybe a different subdomain but the same domain nevertheless.  Unfortunately, we're getting hit w/ "CSRF token missing or incorrect." errors.  How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you passing the CSRF token back to django?

Check out the CSRF docs 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#exceptions
There is lots of good info there.

For example, note about subdomains:

> Subdomains
>   By default, CSRF cookies are specific to the subdomain they are set
>   for. This means that a form served
>   from one subdomain (e.g.
>   server1.example.com) will not be able
>   to have a target on another subdomain
>   (e.g. server2.example.com). This
>   restriction can be removed by setting
>   CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN to be something
>   like ".example.com".

You could also disable CSRF protection for whatever view is throwing that error (in link above) via the `@csrf_exempt` decorator.

Comment: He won't have a CSRF token if the user starts on the perl front end. The @csrf_exempt decorator is the way to go here.